# Retag or Synonym pxe & pxeboot

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

The tags [pxe](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/pxe) (89) and [pxeboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/pxeboot) (15) are the same thing. Could we create a synonym for these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

done -- I agree that [pxeboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/pxeboot) is the better master tag, and the synonym was created as well.

Answer (score 2):

As usual it's the lesser used that should be the parent of the synonym.

Comment: You reckon [pxeboot] should be the primary tag?